# Does using membership provider in the model of a MVC project mean the model knows it is part of a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My basic design is that the model is in a separate project from my website, and the project never references the website.  That tends to enforce the model being agnostic of how it is being used.

But recently I was trying to work in membership provider, and while the register portion of it sounds like something the model would handle (adding the user data to the database), it requires my to reference system.web.security, which would imply the model now knows it is being used in a website.

Am I being too pedantic about the name of the namespace or should membership provider be only used in the web app portion and not the model?

P.S.  Not sure it if matters, but everything outside of membership provider is handled by NHibernate.

Comment: Given the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635614/using-websecurity-with-net-winforms-application, you are indeed creating a unwanted dependency on the web app in your model.